# Proof about subespaces in linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry if my english is not proper, but english its not my first languague and asking question about math is not simple. This is also my first question in the forum.

Does anyone have a proof for this? W1 and W2 are subespaces of a vectorial space V. We have that V = W1 + W2, and the intersection of W1 and W2 is the set with only 0 in it. I need to proof that, if v in V there exist only one vectors w1 in W1 and w2 in W2 such that v = w1 + w2.

Thanks.

Comment: By definition, $W_1 + W_2$ is the set of all sums $w_1 + w_2,$ with $w_i \in W_i$ ($i = 1,2$). Thus, given $v \in V,$ we may find two vectors $w_1$ and $w_2$ such that $v = w_1 + w_2.$ If $w_1'$ and $w_2'$ are another two vectors satisfying the same, then $v = w_1 + w_2 = w_1' + w_2',$ and rearrenging gives $u = w_1 - w_1' = w_2' - w_2.$ But $W_1$ and $W_2$ are vector subspaces, so $u \in W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}.$ Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there exist $u_{1}, w_{1} \in W_{1}$ and $u_{2}, w_{2} \in W_{2}$ such that $u_{1} + u_{2} = v = w_{1} + w_{2}$.
Then $u_{1} - w_{1} = w_{2} -u_{2}$.

This means $u_{1} - w_{1}, w_{2} -u_{2} \in W_{1} \cap W_{2} = \{0 \}$.

But then we have $u_{1} = w_{1}$ and $u_{2} = w_{2}$.